# Authenticate with ADFS without Javascript?

Tags: authentication, javascript, adfs

I'm trying to allow a search engine that doesn't support javascript to crawl content protected by ADFS.

Is there a way to allow clients that don't support javascript to authenticate to an ADFS protected web site?

Out of the box, the ADFS login form relies on Javascript, switching to NTLM allows authentication to succeed but then the final redirect gets stuck because without javascript a submit button is presented.

Comment: I think there are some web services that the ADFS administrator can enable. I'd love to know if you ever figured this out.

Comment: Bit of a late follow up @matteisenberg, but no I didn't figure this out. I worked around it from memory.